# Как добавить условия try catch для цикла do while?

Tags: c++

Хочу выполнять цикл бесконечно если есть ошибка catch, если ошибки нету пусть цикл будет завершен

Пример

```
do
{
    try
    {
      // код какой то программы
    }
    catch (const exception& ex)
    {
        // ошибка 1
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // критическая ошибка 2
    }

} while (// что сюда нужно вставить? это и есть главный вопрос);
```

Получается не важно какая произойдет ошибка 1 или критическая ошибка 2 цикл должен повторить пока не исчезнет ошибка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(;;)
{
    try
    {
        // код какой-то программы
        break;
    }
    catch (const exception& ex)
    {
        // ошибка 1
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // критическая ошибка 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Во этот вариант кручи :)
Интересный вопрос почему тут используется for ведь он вроде больше требует чем while

Comment: @menfix оптимизатор такой цикл (с всегда выполнимым условием) независимо от for или while одинаково реализует в бинарный исполнимый код. Поведение для  for или while в даном случае не будет отличатся, как и исполнимый код.

Comment: @menfix Почему вдруг больше? В нем даже условие отсутствует (по сравнению со вариантом `while (true)`? )

Comment: Чисто технически если подумать то for имеет больше возможностей, значит и сама функция использует код больше чем while ведь все эти функции написаны где то в файле на ассемблере или на каком то другом языке.

Comment: @menfix `for` - это не функция, не написано в каком-то файле и в таком варианте оно вообще работает как безусловный переход.

Comment: Хотите сказать что `for(;;)` лучше чем `while (true)`?
Оба являются бесконечным циклом но разве правильно использовать цикл `for` таким способом и дает ли это производительности?

Comment: Возможно это зависит от людей типа, как красивей сделать код.
С другой стороны зачем тогда был создан цикл while  если он почти бесполезен и не имеет ничего уникального.

Comment: Я уверен что на программном уровне `for` вызывает `;` 2 раза именно поэтому он требует написать 2 раза `;` когда цикл `while` исполняет код после первого раза.

Comment: @menfix Да, `for(;;)` лучше, чем `while (true)`. Первый вариант не содержит условия перехода, а второй - содержит. Этот условный переход может быть устранен и превращен в безусловный переход компилятором на этапе оптимизации. *"на программном уровне for вызывает ; 2 раза"* - такое описание не имеет ничего общего с реальностью.

Comment: хорошо раз вы говорите что `for(;;)` лучше значит дам лидирующий позицию вашему коду. Если кто то захочет оспорить решения раздел открытый :)

Comment: while (true), do while(true) и for(;;) скомпилируются в абсолютно одинаковый код даже с -O0. Вопрос исключительно читаемости. Даже `int i = 0; while(i < 5) {/*do do something*/; ++i}` и `for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {/*do do something*/;}` скомпилятся в одно и тоже.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как сказал @VTT у цикла `for(;;)` нету перехода это можно увидеть во время проверки на ошибки.
Сам же переход не понятно что означает, но если он так же является частью цикла, то при множество запросах этот переход умножает любое вычисления в 2 раза
Типа как это работает, идет цикл `while` каждый цикл спрашивает верно или нет?
когда цикл `for(;;)` вообще ничего не спрашивает. Он просто выполняет цикл вечно пока не встретит `break;`

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко *"while (true), do while(true) и for(;;) скомпилируются в абсолютно одинаковый код даже с -O0"* - это утверждение легко опровергнуть, https://godbolt.org/z/BDsLpN На самом деле не факт что даже со включенными оптимизациями все существующие компиляторы смогут соптимизировать `while(true)`.

Comment: @VTT, как не странно там и проверял. Но до виндового не докрутил. Окей, на виндовом компилятор нужно хотя-бы O1. Не сильно меняет дело, учитывая, что везде О2 или О3. На GCC и clang даже без оптимизации код одинаковый.

Answer (score 1):

> Хочу выполнять цикл бесконечно если есть ошибка catch, если ошибки нету пусть цикл будет завершен

```
while (true) {  // запускаем бесконечный цикл
  try {
    ........  // что-то делаем
    break;  // если дошли сюда - ошибок не было, цикл прерываем
  } catch (...) {
    ........  // обрабатываем ошибки
  }
}
```

Comment: А вот этот еще кручу, сейчас лидирует этот :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true)
```

если хотите бесконечный цикл, пока не снгенерируется исключение. Во первых вы ошибаетесь: не в обработчике  произойдет ошибка, а ошибка произойдет в блоке `try`, и если генерировано исключение, обработчики его обработают, и после этого начнется раскрутка стэка, т.е. весь код после них будет игнорирован, таким ообразом цикл прекратится